# C# .NET - Read a csv file from URL and open it in the browser with Save and open button options

Tags: file, url, csv

I have a URL to the csv file and I need a code in C#.net to read the file from this url and open it in the browser..basically allow an option for save and open. I am trying to use System.Net.WebClient
Can anyone pls help on this..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done that in a long time (before .net actually), but the recipe was :

```
//grab the csv file
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
var fileContent = wc.DownloadString("your url here");
// Clear and set the headers accordingly to the desired action
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content","text/plain");
// send the data and say goodbye
Response.Write(fileContent);
Response.Flush();
```

Note that I'm most certainly wrong on the mime-type settings, but you should find that easily.

Comment: Thanks Pierrecouzy..but this is a silverlight app and response wouldnt work here as i cant get the reference for system.web